# Split a column of full name in to a column of first and last name when it's separated by space in R

Tags: r, split

I have a data frame with one of the columns consisting of a full_name, instead of this I would like to have a column of firs_name and last_name.

For example: say my data is called datta

```
head(datta)

    full_name       V1    V2
    lee yees        4     4
    jhon morgan     4     5
    lebron tom      5     5
```

I would like to get:

```
head(datta)       
first_name  last_name  V1  V2
lee         yees       4   4
jhon        morgan     4   5
lebron      tom        5   5
```

I saw a similar question here in the link

[Efficient way to split a vector of a full name in to 2 separate vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38530579/efficient-way-to-split-a-vector-of-a-full-name-in-to-2-separate-vectors)

The only difference is that in that question the names were separated by a comma and in my data it is separated by space.
I tried to apply what was shown on the answers just using space instead of a comma.

```
lst <- strsplit(val.vec,' ')
v1 <- lapply(lst, `[`, 1)
v2 <- lapply(lst, `[`, 2)
```

It didn't work; it returned a list where each element is one object the first and last name.

Comment: replacing `lapply` with `sapply` should return the vector that you are looking for. Alternatively using `unlist(lapply(lst, `[`, 1))` would work.

Comment: how would I do this when some elements have multtiple space beetween them?

Comment: the second argument to `strsplit` is a regular expression. So you could use `strsplit(val.vec,' +')` to capture multiple spaces in between the first and last names.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(datta, full_name, into = c("first_name", "last_name"))
#   first_name last_name V1 V2
#1        lee      yees  4  4
#2       jhon    morgan  4  5
#3     lebron       tom  5  5
```

---

Or using `read.table` from `base R`

```
cbind(read.table(text=datta$full_name, header=FALSE, 
           col.names = c("first_name", "last_name")), datta[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `stringr`

```
datta %>% mutate(first_name = word(full_name,1),last_name = word(full_name,2))
```